# can't mock the object in the junit testing

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I have a code below need to do the unit testing

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class XC implements Serializable {
   public void applyX(){    
       FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

       if (!context.isValidationFailed()) {
          try {...
    }
 }
```

I wrote a testing code to mock the context. The full class is below.

```
package com.xyx.abc.admin.view.test;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import com.xyx.abc.admin.view.XsltConfig;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({FacesContext.class})
public class XsltConfigTest {

  private XsltConfig xc;

  @Mock
  private FacesContext context;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {

    xc = new XsltConfig();

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    context = PowerMockito.mock(FacesContext.class);
    when(context.isValidationFailed()).thenReturn(false);
    // PowerMockito.mockStatic(FacesContext.class);
    when(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).thenReturn(context);

  }

  /*
   * @Before public void init() { MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); }
   */

  @Test
  public void testApplyXslt() {
    String theXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\r\n" + "<?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"example.xsl\"?>\r\n" + "<Article>\r\n"
        + "  <Title>My Article</Title>\r\n" + "  <Body>This is my article text.</Body>\r\n" + "</Article>";
    xc.setSampleXml(theXml);
    String theXslt = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\r\n" + "<xsl:stylesheet version=\"1.0\" xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\">\r\n"
        + "\r\n" + "  <xsl:output method=\"text\"/>\r\n" + "\r\n" + "  <xsl:template match=\"/\">\r\n"
        + "    Article - <xsl:value-of select=\"/Article/Title\"/>\r\n" + "    Authors: <xsl:apply-templates select=\"/Article/Authors/Author\"/>\r\n"
        + "  </xsl:template>\r\n" + "\r\n" + "  <xsl:template match=\"Author\">\r\n" + "    - <xsl:value-of select=\".\" />\r\n"
        + "  </xsl:template>\r\n" + "\r\n" + "</xsl:stylesheet>";
    xc.setSampleXslt(theXslt);
    String theResult = "Article - My Article";
    xc.setXsltResult(theResult);


    xc.applyXslt();
    // assertEquals(theResult, xc.getXsltResult());
  }

}
```

I always got the below error. It seems it's at the class loading time .

> java.lang.ClassFormatError: JVMCFRE074 no Code attribute specified;
>   class=javax/faces/context/FacesContext, method='<'init'>'()V, pc=0    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:346)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:154)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:727)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$400(URLClassLoader.java:95)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1182)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:686)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:602)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:846)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:825)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:325)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:805)     at
>   java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)   at
>   sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:126)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:137)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:61)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseSig(AnnotationParser.java:451)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassValue(AnnotationParser.java:432)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:736)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:543)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:367)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:298)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:132)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:84)
>     at java.lang.Class.getAnnotationCache(Class.java:2539)  at
>   java.lang.Class.getAnnotations(Class.java:2229)   at
>   org.junit.runner.Description.createSuiteDescription(Description.java:123)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.ErrorReportingRunner.getDescription(ErrorReportingRunner.java:25)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:85)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

Comment: I think your error is on `if (!context.isValidationFailed())`. You don't define that behavior for the mock.

Comment: I used the two lines under the line //alternative, it didn't work either. Thought?

Comment: 1. Put the full class which you are testing. 2. what is XC 3. where is your FacesContext. Put all the details

Comment: added the full test class. full stack trace

Comment: check another post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49310975/maven-plugin-override-not-work