# maven plugin override not work

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a plugin in the parent pom with the below code:

```
        <!-- Test Plugin -->
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${surefire.plugin.version}</version>
      <configuration>

        <!-- Used for JaCoCo Plugin -->
        <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>

        <!-- Used for SonarQube Analysis -->
        <reportsDirectory>../target/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>

      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

The in the child pom, I want to exclude the javaee-api.jar in the build path of test scope as below shows.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration combine.self="override">
              <classpathDependencyExcludes>
                <classpathDependencyExclude>javax:javaee-api</classpathDependencyExclude>
              </classpathDependencyExcludes>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
```

But the javaee-api.jar is still showing in the classpath. Any thought?

> ons-collections4\4.1\commons-collections4-4.1.jar, C:\Users\y2944.m2\repository\commons-dbutils\commons-dbutils\1.6\commons-dbutils-1.6.jar, C:\Users\y2944.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.17\log4j-1.2.17.jar, C:\Users\y2944.m2\repository\javax\faces
>   \javax.faces-api\2.1\javax.faces-api-2.1.jar, C:\Users\y2944.m2\repository\javax\servlet\javax.servlet-api\3.0.1\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar, C:\Users\y2944.m2\repository\com\csx\services\xx\nas-engine-api\1.1.0\nas-engine-api-1.1.0.jar, C:\Users\y
>   2944.m2\repository**javax\javaee-api\7.0**\javaee-api-7.0.jar, C:\Users\y2944.m2\repository\com\sun\mail\javax.mail\1.5.0\javax.mail-1.5.0.jar, C:\Users\y2944.m2\repository\javax\activation\activation\1.1\activation-1.1.jar, C:\Users\y2944.m2\reposi
>   tory\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.1\commons-lang3-3.1.jar, C:\Users\y2944.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\1.3.2\commons-io-1.3.2.jar, C:\Users\y2944.m2\repository\org\primefaces\primefaces\6.0.18\primefaces-6.0.18.jar, C:\Users\y2944.m2\
>   repository\org\apache\poi\poi-ooxml\3.10.1\poi-ooxml-3.10.1.jar, C:\Users\y2944.m2\repository\org\apache\poi\poi\3.10.1\poi-3.10.1.jar, C:\Users\y2944.m2\repository\org\apache\poi\poi-ooxml-schemas\3.10.1\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10.1.jar, C:\Users\y294
>   4.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlbeans\xmlbeans\2.6.0\xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar, C:\Users\y2944.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar, C:\Users\y2944.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlbeans\xmlbeans-qname\2.6.0\xmlbeans-qname-2.6.0.jar, C:\Users\y2944.
>   m2\repository\org\apache\xmlbeans\xmlbeans-xmlpublic\2.6.0\xmlbeans-xmlpublic-2.6.0.jar]

Answer (score 0):

It's the issue with javaee-api.jar with interface only, no implementation. And the exclusion didn't work. So I added the implementation on the test scope.

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>`
```